# How to get child properties from spring config

Tags: java, spring

I have the following configuration:

```
external:
  shop-service:
    url: localhost:8080
    timeout: 5000
  pet-service:
    url: localhost:8081
    timeout: 10000
  user-service:
    url: localhost:8082
    timeout: 15000
```

I want to create some config library that will read these properties in every my service. In every service I can have different clients with different values of properties, but all of them have the same structure.

Any ways how I can get a map that will contain client name as a key and object that has `url` and `timeout` values, if I know only `external` property at the beginning and don't know exact client names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution

```
private static final String BASE_PROPERTY = "clients.";
private static final String DELIMITER = ".";

private final org.springframework.core.env.Environment environment;

public Set<String> getClientNames() {
    return Arrays
        .stream(((EnumerablePropertySource<?>) ((ConfigurableEnvironment) environment)
            .getPropertySources()
            .stream()
            .filter(OriginTrackedMapPropertySource.class::isInstance)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)).getPropertyNames())
        .filter(currentValue -> StringUtils.startsWith(currentValue, BASE_PROPERTY))
        .map(key -> StringUtils.substringBetween(key, DELIMITER, DELIMITER))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration class which maps your properties into a map.

```
@Getter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Properties {
    
    private Map<String, String[]> external = new HashMap<>();
    
}
```

In my opinion, you should avoid using String array as value type. Instead of, you should create a POJO to map the url and timeout properties.

```
@Getter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Properties {

    private Map<String, Data> external = new HashMap<>();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public static class Data {
        private long timeout;
        private String url;
    }
    
}
```

**Note**: the Properties class must have a getter for the map, and the Data properties must have a getter and setter for each attribute.

Comment: both options don't work for me